# Higgs coupling to particles

Tags: mass, standard-model, higgs

Plain question: Is it already solved why the Higgs couples different to various particles (causing distinct mass scales)? Or is it still an ongoing topic?

Can't find an information about the current status.

Comment: Couples in current particle physics  means the coupling constant in the vertices of the feynman diagrams , weak strong electromagnetic ( and maybe gravitational). Do you mean why it gives different masses to different elementary particle sin the particle table of the standard model?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model

Comment: In the standard model the masses of the particles are not derived but are taken as given constants from measurement. For extensions of the standard model it is a matter of research whether an extended model can have less masses  as assumed constants, using various symmetries. see https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.7065 as an example of research